# Azure batch task dependencies: copy files from previous

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-batch

I have a Azure Batch scenario where I have a chain of Tasks which are run after each other. Dependencies are set correctly so they run nicely after each other.

However I need to copy all files from the previous Task's folder to the new Task's folder before execution. I do not know in advance how many and what files there will be so I just want to copy everything. I could not find a way to accomplish this with the Batch client library (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/batch?view=azure-dotnet).

As a workaround I tried adding a simple copy task to the .bat file which is executed with `commandline` but for some reason it only copies some of the files. In one task there are a few hundred files to copy and it varies a few % how big portion it copies before it stops copying (with no errors). This is my copy command: `$"cmd /c xcopy /E /F /Y %AZ_BATCH_TASK_WORKING_DIR%\\..\\..\\{previousTaskId}\\wd %AZ_BATCH_TASK_WORKING_DIR%"`. Everything works correctly if performed directly from the VM.

Tested hypothesis:

- Copying overwrites the .bat file which executes the actual processing. This in turn breaks the copying. I've now ruled out this problem (each task has a differently named .bat file)
- Copying is done for some reason in parallel. I added timestamp echos to the bats and there is no parallelism so this can't be the reason. Also tried adding `sleep 10` before the xcopy but didn't make any difference.
- xcopy wouldn't see all the files for some reason. Added a `dir` command to see what files there are and it sees only the same files which xcopy copies.
- user access issues. Doesn't make sense as some files are copied succesfully and there are no errors.

Any ideas? This sounds like a trivial scenario but I just couldn't figure out how to do this.

Comment: Is that your new task needs the previous tasks' output files?

Comment: yes and I can't know exactly which and how many output files so it's ok if everything is copied

Comment: Is that your store these files in your nodes?

Comment: All of these tasks are executed in a single node. I don't do parallelism.

Comment: Could you please tell me your error? I think you can connect to your node and manually copy files by yourself.

Comment: I don't have any error message. I simply don't know how to automatically copy files from the previous task. Adding the explicit xcopy command copies only some of the files for some reason. And yes, I can manually copy files if I connect to the node but that's not the point

Comment: As far as I know, the file on the node has the lifetime? Could you please check if all the files on the node? For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-task-output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201079/discussion-between-lauri-peltonen-and-jim-xu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was in the previous Task: it launched a process which started generating the files in the background and returned control immediately. Therefore the Batch engine thought the Task had finished and continued to the next Task which was first copying the files generated by the previous Task.

My hypothesis about parallelism was therefore partially true although it wasn't visible with echoing timestamps (first Task said it finished before second Task said it started). The experiment with `sleep` would've revealed the problem but I either used too short sleep delay or somehow read the results wrong.

Because I can't control how the first Task launches the process I now added some Windows Batch script to poll `tasklist` about when the process ends and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What do you have configured as your [`retentionTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/task/add#taskconstraints) for your tasks?

I'm wondering if Batch is cleaning up the previous task (removing all the files) at the same time as your downstream task is trying to copy them.

An untested suggestion ...

... assuming you have tasks A & B that run in that order (enforced using Task Dependencies).

... configure [`outputFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/task/add#outputfile) on task A to copy all of the files generated by `A` into your storage account. Use wildcards so that all the files are copied into the same container.

... configure [`resourceFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/task/add#resourcefile) on task B to copy all the files from your storage account into the task working directory.

This has the advantage of preserving your intermediate working files off the compute node - allowing you to pick up where you left off if/when something interrupts your workload.

Comment: It was't cleaning the files; everything worked just fine if I performed the commands manually in the VM. And as for your proposed solution, I'd have to know the input resource files in advance to be able to create a ResourceFile out of them - I don't know them in advance. Anyway, I found the problem, more in my answer. Thanks for the input!