# How should I transfer files between consequent Batch Tasks?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-batch

I have a bunch of Azure Batch Tasks (Windows) which are dependent on each other so that they are executed one after another. There is only one Job. Each Task requires all of the files generated in the previous Task (plus whatever files the previous Task got from its previous Task).

How should I transfer these files between the Tasks? My current solution is to execute a move command at the start of each commandLine for each Task. This move command moves all files from the previous Task's folder to the current Task's folder. This kinda works but doesn't seem right and I don't have any backup about the intermediary results.

I was thinking of setting all of the files as `output` for each Task (to Blob Storage) and setting them as `input` for the next Task but this doesn't work because I would have to know all files in advance to generate `ResourceFile` references for them. I don't know in advance which files will get generated. So my next best idea is to generate a ResourceFile reference for a single ZIP file which contains whatever contents the previous Task zipped into it. So the ZIP file's contents would change all the time but I can add it as `input` because I can create a `ResourceFile` reference to it (even if the file's contents change). But this seems rather cumbersome.

Other ideas?

P.S. This is related to my earlier question at [Azure batch task dependencies: copy files from previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58444889/azure-batch-task-dependencies-copy-files-from-previous) which mentions this same problem but asks a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you likely want is to mount a virtual file system on the pool allowing shared access. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/virtual-file-mount

Answer (score 2):

I think there are few things you are do, considering you are already exploring the `output` file approach.

2 more ideas below:

***Idea 1:***

Using the azurefileshare for mounting in windows VMs.

**Note:** Since the VMs you got are `Windows` I think which limits your chance of using the `blobfuse` driver for `blobstorage` mount. ALthough if the `azurefileshare` is something you can use as the mounting point then you can use the feature in Batch called [Mounting Virtual Filesystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-task-output-files#specify-output-files-for-task-output) and [AzureFileSahre](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-task-output-files#specify-output-files-for-task-output) in particular for windows vms.

Here as well you need to make sure that there is the `task Dependency` in place so that for example `task1` finishes first and then the output of that file can be accessed by the `task 2` form mounted drive.

***Idea 2:***

Like you mention use persisting [output file concept](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-task-output-files#specify-output-files-for-task-output) along with conceptually making that task dependent on the task which will first generate the outputfile and once it's persisted the task which needs to use those files can trigger the download for resrouefile.

**Pros for idea1:**

Once mounted the drive is available in all windows node as drive so the download and upload time is curtailed. (Only the drive sync time latency remains, which should be few milliseconds - this should not be noticeable).

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. I implemented File Share (option 1) yesterday and it seems to work, although I never got the Pool's Mounting configuration to work so I do it manually via `net use`. The delay for upload+download is a few minutes per Task but that's irrelevant as one Task execution may take days. As for your second idea I fail to see how it differs from what I've outlined already in my question - I can only use ResourceFiles for files which I know exist and I don't know in advance which/what files will be generated